# Redirect all path except a few in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Id like to use the `.htaccess` file on an apache servier redirect all paths on a given domain to a new location but keep a few specific URLs live.

```
Redirect 301 /(.*) www.example.com

# but not /foo
# but not /bar 
# but not /baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it using `Redirect` directive. I suggest using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(?:foo|bar|baz)[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: thank you! Im finding the `RewriteRule` is working but the `RewriteCond` seems not to be triggering. /foo, /bar, /baz are all being redirected as per `RewiteRule`

Comment: yes, correct. `/foo, /bar, /baz` should NOT be redirected but they still are given the rules posted

Comment: yep, top of .htaccess & cache cleared - still redirecting

Comment: just the source URL with /foo etc. (i.e. http://www.sourceexample.com/foo)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222317/discussion-between-anubhava-and-yevg).